# php: Regex and the caret

Tags: php, regex

So I'm trying to make a regex to include the course contents of a text, but exclude the 3 digit numbers followed by a period and some text. Basically I'm trying to divide the course text into individual courselines, so that I end up with an array where every element has the courseinfo of one class.

For example, suppose we have:

$text = "295. Student-Initiated Courses or Projects. (1-2)
Open to students who have completed the first-year curriculum. Clinical work, field work, legal assistance, individual research and writing, writing or editing for profes¬sional journals, student-taught courses, or other legal projects of a serious, educational nature. Requires the approval of the Law 295 Administrator and the Dean.
296. Legal Dissertation. (8-13)"

and this giant regex:

```
$lineDelimiter = ='/(?:[0-9]{3}(?:\.5|\-[1-5])?[A-Z]?)(?:\-[0-9]{3}(?:\.5|\-[0-9])?  [A-Z]?)?\.\s*.+\.\s*(?:(?:\([0-9]+\-*[0-9]*\))(?:\s*or\s*\([0-9]+\-*[0-9]*\))?)?\s*(?:Prerequisite)?.+(?:\n.+)?\.\n?(?:\s*Mr\.\s.+,?|\s*Ms\.\s.+,?|\s*Dr\.\s.+,?|\s*The\sFaculty.*,?)*[^(?:[0-9]{3}\..+)]/';
```

The very last part of that giant regex, which consists of

```
'/[^(?:[0-9]{3}\..+)]/'
```

errors when I preg_match_all.

I'm trying to exclude the "296. Legal Dissertation. (8-13)" part so that it will be

"295. Student-Initiated Courses or Projects. (1-2)
Open to students who have completed the first-year curriculum. Clinical work, field work, legal assistance, individual research and writing, writing or editing for profes¬sional journals, student-taught courses, or other legal projects of a serious, educational nature. Requires the approval of the Law 295 Administrator and the Dean."

Comment: show how you're using it please.

Comment: shouldn't it be `'/^(?:[0-9]{3}\..+)/'` ?

Comment: @ITroubs He needs to be negative, so the regex must exclude and not match the numbers and the rest.

Comment: Could you say what are you trying to achieve with this text?

Comment: It's not clear (at least not to me) what you want to do. what does "I want to exclude the 296. Legal Dissertation part" mean in terms of what you _do_ want to match? I.e. what is your desired result? And what's that second regex..?

Comment: @HaralanDobrev that might be but my regex tool shows me an error with his regex string saying "expected end of string at position 17" if I feed it the `[^(?:[0-9]{3}\..+)]` and as far as i know the [] brakets are there to enclode possible characters and not whole regex strings!

Comment: You can't have group (indicated by parens) inside a character class (indicated by square brackets).

Comment: So how would I go about excluding the aforementioned group?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match everything except the last part with the number and the text you could try this:

```
'/([\s\S]+)(?=\d{3}\..+)/'
```

- `[\s\S]+` matches everything - both whitespace and non-whitespace
- `(?=)` performs [`Positive Lookahead`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It does not match the things in the brackets, but it makes sure the stuff before the brackets is followed by this in the brackets.
- `\d{3}\..+` matches 3 digits followed by a dot and some other characters without new lines.

Comment: It still doesn't work, when I replace the end of the giant regex with this.

Comment: @user2192620 I have updated my answer, explanation following soon.